# How do i change an image into a different image by clicking on it with onclick?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How do i change an image into a different image by clicking on it with onclick?

```css
#box{ height:200px; width:200px; background-color:gold; }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="box"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("box").onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById("box").style.display = ???? 
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: * into a different image* - replace with another element?

Answer (score 0):

Update [`backgroundImage` property in `style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference) of html element

```
document.getElementById("image1").onclick = function() {
   this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img.jpg)'
}
```

```css
#box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("image1").onclick = function() {
    this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img.jpg)';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong but it is not working.

Comment: <style>

#box{
height:200px;
width:200px;
background-color:gold;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>




<div id="box"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("box").onclick=function() {

this.src ="shoe.jpg"

}

















</script>

Answer (score 0):

**With jQuery:**

```
$('your_image_id_or_selector').click(function(){
   $(this).attr('src','new_image_url');
});
```

Comment: Thank You sir but i have not started Jquery yet so i have no idea how to read that yet but thanks anyway!